# algoritmo em pascal com erro de execução

Tags: pascal

Fiz esse algoritmo mas ele não executo, aparece um erro, "else não esperado":

```
Program valormaior_oumenor ;
    var
    valornicial, valorfinal:integer;
Begin
    writeln('Digite um valor ');
    read(valorinicial);
    writeln('Digite outro valor ');
    read(valorfinal);
    if (valorinicial>valorfinal) then
        while (valorinicial>=valorfinal) do
            writeln('valorinicial')
            valorinicial:=valorinicial+1
    else
        while  (valorinicial<=valorfinnal) do
        writeln(valorfinal)
        valorfinal:=valorinicial-1

End.
```

Comment: não dá pra entender nada!

Comment: já conferiu se não falta um `being`,  `end` ou simplesmente um `;`?

Answer (score 3):

Faltam o begin e o end para os if e algumas variáveis estavam escritas diferente da declaração.

```
program valormaior_oumenor ;
Uses Crt;
    var
    valorinicial, valorfinal:integer;
begin
    writeln('Digite um valor ');
    read(valorinicial);
    writeln('Digite outro valor ');
    read(valorfinal);
    if (valorinicial>valorfinal) then
    begin
        while (valorinicial>=valorfinal) do
        begin  
          writeln('valorinicial');
          valorinicial:=valorinicial+1;
        end
    end    
    else
    begin
        while  (valorinicial<=valorfinal) do
        writeln(valorfinal);
        valorfinal:=valorinicial-1;
    end;
end.
```